How to Run Python Apache Beam with AWS Managed Apache Flink?
I'm trying to figure out how to run simple Apache Beam using Python using AWS Managed Apache Flink as a runner
The application couldn't even start due to the following exception, while there are almost no information/tutorials that would allow to avoid it (generally there are only Java Beam app examples for Managed Flink for AWS):
--------------------------- Python Process Started --------------------------  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
    File "/tmp/flink-web-5d98ef0c-f0f3-429e-ba53-60655903bff0/flink-web-upload/dac34d18-5e05-4c0c-ba49-f1b9d60dc8f9_code/main.py", line 53, in module  
        main()  
    File "/tmp/flink-web-5d98ef0c-f0f3-429e-ba53-60655903bff0/flink-web-upload/dac34d18-5e05-4c0c-ba49-f1b9d60dc8f9_code/main.py", line 36, in main  
        p  
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/ptransform.py", line 1110, in __ror__  
        return self.transform.__ror__(pvalueish, self.label)  
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/ptransform.py", line 623, in __ror__  
        result = p.apply(self, pvalueish, label)  
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 679, in apply  
        return self.apply(transform, pvalueish)  
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 741, in apply  
        pvalueish_result = self.runner.apply(transform, pvalueish, self._options)  
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/runner.py", line 203, in apply  
        return self.apply_PTransform(transform, input, options)  
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/runner.py", line 207, in apply_PTransform  
        return transform.expand(input)  
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/external.py", line 751, in expand  
        with ExternalTransform.service(expansion_service) as service:  
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/contextlib.py", line 137, in __enter__  
        return next(self.gen)  
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/external.py", line 807, in service  
        with expansion_service as stub:  
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/external.py", line 1013, in __enter__  
        self._path_to_jar = subprocess_server.JavaJarServer.local_jar(  
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/utils/subprocess_server.py", line 376, in local_jar  
        os.makedirs(cache_dir)  
    File "frozen os", line 215, in makedirs  
    File "frozen os", line 225, in makedirs  
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/amazon/.apache_beam'  
--------------------------- Python Process Exited ---------------------------  

The job code i'm trying to run is the following:
(it's possible that the code itself is not working but I didn't even get a chance to run it before the exception is thrown)
import logging

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io import WriteToText
from apache_beam.io.kafka import ReadFromKafka
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions



def format_as_json(element):
    import json
    return json.dumps(element)


def main():
    options = {
        'output_bucket': 'test',
        'topic_name': 'test',
        "bootstrap_servers": "servers...."
    }
    topic = options.topic_name
    bootstrap_servers = options.bootstrap_servers
    s3_bucket_name = options.output_bucket
    consumer_config = {
        "bootstrap.servers": bootstrap_servers,
        "security.protocol": "SASL_SSL",
        "sasl.mechanism": "AWS_MSK_IAM",
        "sasl.jaas.config": "software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;",
        "sasl.client.callback.handler.class": "software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler",
    }

    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()
    pipeline_options._all_options['streaming'] = True
    pipeline_options._all_options['enable_streaming_engine'] = True

    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
        s = (
                p
                | 'ReadFromKafka' >> ReadFromKafka(consumer_config=consumer_config, topics=[topic])
                | 'Format as JSON' >> beam.Map(format_as_json)
                | 'Print' >> beam.Map(lambda x: log_value(x))
                | 'Write to S3' >> WriteToText(
                    file_path_prefix=f's3://{s3_bucket_name}/flink/new/',
                    file_name_suffix='.json'
                )
        )


def log_value(x):
    logging.info(x)
    return x


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

The configuration as advised in AWS Documentation, the zip archive is built accordingly and all necessary service permissions are provided as well. pyflink-dependencies.jar contains only single dependency for aws-msk-iam-auth.



Group
Key
right




kinesis.analytics.flink.run.options
jarfile
lib/pyflink-dependencies.jar


kinesis.analytics.flink.run.options
pyFiles
site-packages/


kinesis.analytics.flink.run.options
python
main.py




For the original issue related to "frozen os" I was able to workaround using the following monkey-patching of the hardcoded path:
import apache_beam.utils.subprocess_server
apache_beam.utils.subprocess_server.JavaJarServer.JAR_CACHE = '/tmp/apache_beam_temp_directory/cache/jars'

However, at the moment Apache Beam Python SDK is not supported for Managed Apache Flink
(https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-managed-service-for-apache-flink-examples/issues/54#issuecomment-2312207604)
Basically down the road there are multiple other connectivity issues while trying to run either FlinkRunner or PortableRunner: there are simply no --flink_master/--job_manager endpoints that are able to work correctly with Beam
